# wondering how to return a list with original tuple before its changed

Tags: python

```
dictionary = {'apple': 0, 'banana': 1}

def stores(dictionary,apple):
    z = []
    for x,c in apple:
      dictionary[x] = c
    print(z)
```

as you can see above, I am trying to write a program that get the output that stores all the tuples of dictionary before the last changed and not included last changed value, if the key is not going to change then it will not stored anything(empty list).

i have been trying to work it out but none of them works, any helps will be very appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, it's not very clear what the purpose/use-case of the function is... maybe try explaining it at a higher level (what the function will do in your program) - it seems that it's not really set up in an intuitive way and that might make it more difficult to get it to do what you want it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an undo buffer.  So, only record something just before it's about to change.

```
def stores(dictionary,apple):
    z = []
    for x,c in apple:
        if dictionary[x] != c:
            z.append( (x, dictionary[x]) )
        dictionary[x] = c
    print(z)
```